# How to create Login with Google and Facebook in ionic 1

Tags: android, angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-v1

I'm beginner use ionic framework, I use ionic 1, now I get duty to build app and authentication use Google and Facebook, I use cordova plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/, I follow all steps here https://www.sitepoint.com/authenticating-users-via-oauth-with-cordova-and-ionic/ but I always get error, I run in mobile use 'ionic cordova run android', I don't know why when I click Login I always get Error, please anyone give me step by step how to make Login (Google and Facebook) in ionic 1 use ngcordova.

this is my script

dash.html

```
    <ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h2>Welcome to Ionic</h2>
        <div>
          <a href="" ng-click="googleLogin()"><button>Login With Google</button></a>
          <span>{{details}}</span>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Dash Controller.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $http) {

    $scope.googleLogin = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.google("appId12345.apps.googleusercontent.com", ["email", "profile"]).then(function(result) {
           $scope.details = result.access_token;
        }, function(error) {
           $scope.details = "error";
        });
    }
})
```

please anyone help me. thanks.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I console in error function, I get this error 'Google no longer supports authentication requests from the web view.  More information can be found at https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html', but when I run in mobile I still get error, I print $scope.details, I always get error in view

Comment: 'Google no longer supports authentication requests from the web view. More information can be found at developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/…; It says that the API the plugin uses is deprecated.

Comment: ow, do you know how to create login in ionic wit ngcordova . .?

Comment: For Google :: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework
For Facebook :: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework